# Getting a layout for qubits in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to use Qiskit's built in transpiler passes to do the following. I would like to take a quantum circuit and allocate the logical qubits to physical qubits.

The [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/37f0cd4/qiskit/advanced/terra/4_transpiler_passes_and_passmanager.ipynb) doesn't really explain how to do this. I would like to use one of the preset passes (`TrivialLayout`, `DenseLayout`, etc) to get this allocation.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, passes 
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeMelbourne # NB will need to install dev requirements

""" This is the circuit we are going to look at"""
qc = QuantumCircuit(13, 13)
qc.h(3)
qc.cx(0,6)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(6,0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(3,1)
qc.h(3)
qc.cx(3,0)
qc.measure_all()

backend = FakeMelbourne() 
properties = backend.properties() 
coupling_map = backend.configuration().coupling_map
```

The output of the program should be a dictionary or something that gives tells me which physical qubit each logical qubit is mapped to. How can I do this?

Comment: As a layman I think map must be visual and so, non-visual mapping of dictionary can not be viable. I am not sure !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the last three lines of the code you posted with

```
IBMQ.load_account()
backend = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q').get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
new_circ_lv0 = transpile(qc, backend=backend, optimization_level=0)
plot_circuit_layout(new_circ_lv0, backend)
```

and add the necessary import statements (`plot_circuit_layout` is in `qiskit.visualization`).  This should give you the mapping from your logical qubits to physical qubits on `ibmq_16_melbourne`, with optimization level 0:

[image: physical qubits]

For more information, [this tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/fundamentals/5_using_the_transpiler.ipynb) will probably be more helpful for this task than the one you linked.

Comment: Thank you, that worked nicely. Just to clarify, is there a non visual representation of the mapping e.g. a dictionary?

Comment: @user1936752 The method that the drawer is using is `circuit._layout.get_virtual_bits()` and looking at the [code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/1e0d3ae18aa187ce042dcc0cf46b0f1f42cc9a6a/qiskit/transpiler/layout.py#L176) I think this does what you are looking for.